# jquery autocomplete select messing data

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I can't figure it out why on jquery autocomplete, the select function messes up the data. By that I mean that `value` = `label` when it shouldn't.

Console log output for `console.log(val);`

```
Object { value="1558825", label="Cree sus propias noticias cliente", icon="http://servidor...News/10_ae4e0.jpg"}
```

Console log output for `console.log(ui.item);`

```
Object { label="Cree sus propias noticias cliente", value="Cree sus propias noticias cliente"}
```

Code:

```
$("#search_input").autocomplete({

  source: function(req, add) {

    $.getJSON("do.php", { OP: "news_search", category: cat_id, get: req }, function(results){

      var suggestions = [];

      $.each(results, function(i, val){
        console.log(val);
        suggestions.push(val.label)
      });

      add(suggestions);

    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui){
    console.log(ui.item); // Here value and label is the same, when it shouldn't
    $("#search_input").val(ui.item.label).attr('data-target', ui.item.value);
    return false;
  },
  minLength: 2
});
```

Any ideas why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code  `suggestions.push(val.label)` pushes only label. So you can't get anything other than the label in the `ui` object

Try to push the val object `suggestions.push(val)`

Comment: indeed sir, that was the problem... how stupid of me for not noticing that

Comment: In programming everyone do such mistake. With experience it only gets lessen.

Comment: And @w0rldart, don't call me sir. Here in stack site we all are same. even you can resolve my questions.